# Continuous prompt user for input if the input is not an integer

Tags: c++

What is the simplest method without C++11 that will prompt a user for an integer, and if they do not enter an integer will give them an error message and re-prompt them?

This is what I've tried:

```
int number;
cin >> number;

while(!cin){
   cin.clear();
   cin >> number;
}
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried. You might as well copy-paste an attempt from the 40 or so questions posted here daily with exactly this mechanic.

Comment: Okay, now, what is the problem with your attempt?

Comment: I don't know, that is why I'm asking. It enters an infinite loop.

Comment: You didn't tell us that in your question.

Comment: It's ok if you can't answer my question, just tell me this beforehand.

Comment: Lightness Races in Orbit *can* answer your question (being in the top 0.12% users of this site), he just wants you to put a bit of effort into your question.  You need to make more of an effort on Stack Overflow. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Here is one method, which I copied from the link at the bottom.  There are multiple ways to do this, including reading the number in as a character, if you so choose. But this one should solve your dilemma.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    double teger;
    int teger2;
    do
    {
        std::cout << "enter an int" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> teger;
        std::cin.ignore();
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cout << "you entered: " << teger << std::endl;
        teger2 = teger;
        std::cout << "the int of that is: " << teger2 << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::endl;
        if (teger != teger2) std::cout << "Sorry, that isn't an int, try again." << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::endl;
    } while (teger != teger2);
std::cout << "congrats, you passed the int test" << std::endl;
return 0;
```

}

You can read the following discussion for more examples:

http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/76374/

Comment: -1 Instead of directing the OP to look at another site, you should just copy the few lines of relevant code into your answer here. You can reference the original site as the source of the answer if needed. Do that, and I will reverse my -1.

Comment: @RemyLebeau that link has a pretty lengthy description as well as providing multiple ways to tackle his issue depending on his level of knowledge.  I don't know why you would down rate me, when I'm new to this and noone else was offering anything.

Comment: Answers should be self-contained, so people can search on them and just read them as-is. Besides, external links can and do change over time. I have edited your answer accordingly. As for "noone offering anything", the OP's question was asked only 1 hour ago.  You have to give people time to answer. Wait a few hours, if not a day, before you start criticizing people for not answering.  We don't all live and breathe on StackOverflow 24/7.

Comment: Okay, thanks.  I added some code as you suggested.  I've benefited quite a bit from my little usage of this site and I was excited to give back and I find I learn the most by jumping around with information b/c every situation is different.  Thanks.